# I am not able to generate script using jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-3.2, jmeter-4.0

I am not able to generate script using jmeter.
Getting below error.

```
Response code: 
Response message: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
**ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy certificate**
```

Can some one help what would be the issue. I have already installed `JMeter _CA certificate`.

Comment: And what JMeter version do you actually use?

Answer (score 0):

When you record new script with [JMeter's HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) it generates new certificate. Probably you install several certificates or did not enable checkbox "Trust this CA to identify websites"?

Check this [quick guide for getting started with JMeter Recording](https://www.redline13.com/blog/2016/01/jmeter-recording/)

How to remove old and add new certificate in Firefox:

1. Start Firefox
2. Open menu
3. Options
4. Privacy & Security
5. View Certificates
6. Ensure there are no certificates starts with names "`_DO NOT INSTALL..`", "`DO NOT INSTALL..`", "`JMETER..`", "`_JMETER..`" and other related to JMeter cerificates, and Delete them if they present.
7. Click Import.
8. Navigate to your JMeter bin dir and choose `ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt` file.
9. Check `Trust this CA to identify websites`.
10. Press Ok

[image]